# Find index where type conversion fails in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D numpy array of strings that I need to convert to a new dtype. **The new type may be either an int, float, or datetime type**. Some of the strings may be invalid for that type and cannot be converted, which leads to an error, e.g.:

```
>>> np.array(['10', '20', 'a'], dtype=int)
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

I want to find the index of that invalid value, in this case 2. Currently I can only think of two solutions, neither of which are great:

1. Parse the exception message with a regex to find the invalid value, then find the index of that value in the original array. This seems messy and error-prone.
2. Parse the values in a loop in Python. This would probably be significantly slower than a numpy version. For example, here's an experiment I did:

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

strings = np.array(list(map(str, range(10000000))))


def python_parse(arr):
    result = []
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        try:
            result.append(int(x))
        except ValueError:
            raise Exception(f'Failed at: {i}')


print(timeit(lambda: np.array(strings, dtype=int), number=10))  # 35 seconds
print(timeit(lambda: python_parse(strings), number=10))         # 52 seconds
```

This seems like a simple and common enough operation that I expect a solution to be built into the numpy library, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I overestimated the difference between Python and numpy, and while the Python code I put in the question is quite slow, it can be made much faster using a preallocated array:

```
def python_parse(arr):
    result = np.empty(shape=(len(arr),), dtype=int)
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        try:
            result[i] = x
        except ValueError:
            raise Exception(f'Failed at: {i}')
    return result
```

This produces errors correctly and is almost as fast as simply `np.array(strings, dtype=int)` (which seriously surprised me).

Comment: Note that this seems to only give meaningful output on 1D arrays. Try `arr = np.array(['10', '20', 'a', '4', '%', '2']).reshape(3, 2)`. I guess you'd have to `ravel()` higher dimensions and then work backwards.

Comment: I wonder how surprised you'll be once you try this: change `enumerate(arr)` to `enumerate(arr.tolist())` and timeit again.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I am very surprised, thank you! At first I was really shocked because I thought this made numpy slower than Python, but I see `np.array(strings, dtype=int)` also becomes much faster when I add `.tolist()`.

Comment: No need to panic, there is an explanation: the `__getitem__` method for arrays is significantly more expensive than that for lists. Because (1) it has to be able to parse much more complex indices (2) it has to create a Python object from the "C" element stored in the array whereas the list only needs to return a reference. Now, obviously, `tolist` must create those objects, too, but I'd assume it's cheaper when done in bulk. (3) `tolist` returns native Python objects (like `int` as opposed to `np.int64`) where possible while `__getitem__` doesn't. This also seems to favor list access.

Comment: @PaulPanzer still, it seems like something that could be improved in numpy. I think I'll open an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.core.defchararray.isdigit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.isdigit.html#numpy.core.defchararray.isdigit) to find the indices of the digits and then use a logical-not operand to get the indices of nan-digit items. Afterward you can just use `np.where()` to get the respective indices:

```
In [20]: arr = np.array(['10', '20', 'a', '4', '%'])

In [24]: np.where(~np.core.defchararray.isdigit(arr))
Out[24]: (array([2, 4]),)
```

If you want to check for multiple types like float you can use a custom function and then using `np.vectorize` apply the function to your array. For dates it's a little bit tricky but if you want a general way for that you may want to use `dateutils.parser()`.

You can use a function like following:

```
# from dateutils import parser
In [33]: def check_type(item):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         float(item)
    ...:     except:
    ...:         try:         
    ...:             parser.parse(item)
    ...:         except:     
    ...:             return True
    ...:         else:      
    ...:             return False
    ...:     else:          
    ...:         return False
```

Then:

```
vector_func = np.vectorize(check_type)
np.where(vector_func(arr))
```

Demo:

```
In [45]: arr = np.array(['10.34', '-20', 'a', '4', '%', '2018-5-01'])

In [46]: vector_func = np.vectorize(check_type)
    ...: np.where(vector_func(arr))
    ...: 
Out[46]: (array([2, 4]),)
```

Comment: But I can't use this for floats, datetimes, or negative numbers.

Comment: @AlexHall For those cases you have to use a Python-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. In the end I managed to solve this and I'm afraid I prefer my solution, particularly because it stops at the first error, but I like your idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
custom_type=int
i = 0
l = ['10', '20', 'a']
acc = np.array([], dtype=custom_type)
for elem in l:
    try:
       acc = np.concatenate((acc, np.array([elem], dtype=custom_type)))
       i += 1
    except:
       print("Failed to convert the type of the element in position {}".format(i))
```

Comment: I suspect this is significantly more inefficient than just iterating through a regular Python list, which the OP is already reluctant to do.

Comment: As @roganjosh said, I'm trying to avoid a Python loop.